# AS2 fixed sized movieclip

Tags: actionscript-2, lightbox, scale, movieclip, moviecliploader

I'm working with a Flash website at the moment, and when clicking on a specific hotspot, it opens up a new .swf over the top. This .swf it opens is styled similar to a Lightbox. It has a (x) to close unLoad the movie, along with a (<) and a (>) to navigate through the images.

The problem being, when adjusting the explorer window, the flash elements scale to the adjusted size, staying in proportion.

What I want is, while it's in the HTML page, is to have only the background flash image to scale, but to have the overlaying 'lightbox' .swf at a fixed width/height, so it never scales according to the size of the user's window.

I've found an example to help with this:

http://newsletters.plainpicture.com/static/newsletters/com/news-1208/index.html

Answer (score 0):

how is your "lightbox" swf implemented? is it an actual html lightbox that acts as a container for an external swf movie? or it's your coded lightbox inside the same swf website movie?

if it is html lightbox then you must provide information about what kind of lightbox it is and perhaps look into the lightbox documentation.

if it's your "lightbox" inside the same flash movie, a possible way to resize a specific part of the same swf but not another is to publish the movie (inside "publish settings", ctrl+12) as non-scalable, and resize only a desired part of your movie manually- via the resize event on the stage listener

```
var stageListener:Object = new Object ();
Stage.addListener (stageListener);

orig_ratio=Stage.width/Stage.height;
stageListener.onResize = function(){//resized page
   something_to_resize_only._height=Stage.height;
   something_to_resize_only._width=something_to_resize_only._height*ratio; 
   //...etc etc... you may include current_ratio/orig_ratio comparison conditions too
}
```

if you need help with resizing stuff manually, you should create a new question as it is something irrelevant to this question. don't be afraid though, it's not a difficult task and you may even find a lot of tutorials on proportional scaling/resize